# for monotonic differentiable increasing functions, show $f'(x_0)\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

> Let $X$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$, let $x_0$ be a limit point of $X$, and let $f:X\to \Bbb R$ be a function. If $f$ is monotone increasing and $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $f'(x_0)\geq0$.

Proof:
since $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$,
$\lim_{x\to x_0,x\in X-\{x_0\}} {\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}=L$

This is equivalent to saying:

For every sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which consists entirely of elements of $X-\{x_0\}$, which converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_n\in X-\{x_0\}$, $a_n>x_0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=x_0$, then the sequence $\left(\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}\right)^\infty_{n=0}$ converges to L.

since $a_n>x_0 \implies a_n-x_0>0$

since $f$ is monotonically increasing $\implies f(a_n)>f(x_0)$

Hence, $\left(\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}\right)^\infty_{n=0}\geq 0$

take limit of both sides
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}\geq \lim_{n\to \infty} 0$$

Hence, by the comparison test:
$L\geq 0$ as desired.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You can prove by contradiction. Suppose $f'(x_0)<0$. Then there exists a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that difference quotient is less than 0. Then you can derive a contradiction to the monotone increasing function property. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the core idea, but there are some problems with your write-up. You have:

> since $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$,
> $\lim_{x\to x_0,x\in X-\{x_0\}} {\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}=L$

There’s no reason to introduce $L$, and if you *do* introduce it, you should say what it is. What you mean here is:

> Since $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, $$\lim_{x\to x_0,\,x\in X\setminus\{x_0\}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ exists; as usual we’ll denote it by $f\,'(x_0)$.

Now you have:

> This is equivalent to saying:
>
> For every sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which consists entirely of elements of $X-\{x_0\}$, which converges to $x_0$, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

This is simply wrong: the sentence beginning ‘For every sequence’ actually says that $f$ is *continuous* at $x_0$, which is true but is not equivalent to the statement that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

You continue:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_n\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$, $a_n>x_0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=x_0$,

There may not be such a sequence: it’s possible that $x_0=\inf X$, so that every element of $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ is larger than $x_0$. Don’t worry about it: just let $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be *any* sequence in $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ that converges to $x_0$. (You know that there is one, because $x_0$ is a limit point of $X$.) Now let $n\in\Bbb N$. If $a_n<x_0$, then $f(a_n)\le f(x_0)$, so $f(a_n)-f(x_0)\le 0$ and $a_n-x_0<0$, and hence

$$\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}\ge 0\;.$$

If, on the other hand, $a_n>x_0$, then $f(a_n)\ge f(x_0)$, so $f(a_n)-f(x_0)\ge 0$ and $a_n-x_0>0$, and hence again

$$\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}\ge 0\;.$$

Thus,

$$f\,'(x_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}\ge 0\;,$$

since every term of the sequence

$$\left\langle\frac{f(a_n)-f(x_0)}{a_n-x_0}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$$

is non-negative. (Note that the argument works even when $f$ is not *strictly* increasing.)